# How to strip newlines from a char-array?

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I've put the contents of a file in a char-array using this function:

```
void Read::readFile(){
FILE * fp = fopen(this->filename,"rt");
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
long size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
char *pData = new char[size + 1];
fread(pData, sizeof(char), size, fp);
fclose(fp);
this->data = pData;
}
```

Now I want to strip all line-endings from the char-array.
How do I do this without casting the char-array into a string first?

btw. this is part of a homework where we aren't allowed to use the string-library.

Comment: Why are you using C functions to read files and why don't you want to use the string class to handle string data?

Comment: What do you mean "strip"?  Do you want to copy the entire array somewhere else minus the newlines or replace the newlines with some other character?

Comment: @Duck i think the OP wants to NOT have to do a copy operation

Comment: @Duck and one could arguably also ask , whats this doing flagged with c++ ?

Comment: copying the entire array into another array would be fine. Ignoring the newlines would be the best.
@Matti: This is for a homework for school about pointers, we aren't allowed to use the string-library.

Comment: tagging as homework would have been nice.

Comment: @Kevin I didn't know this tag existed yet. Added it, removed the C++ tag.

Comment: @Hedge: No, don't remove the C++ tag.  This isn't valid C (it uses the C++ scope operator `::`, and `new`, and the `this` keyword).

Comment: Plus the accepted answer wouldn't be correct without a c++ tag

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
#include <algorithm>
size = std::remove(pData, pData + size, '\n') - pData;
pData[size] = 0; // optional
```

For some C++11 lambda fun:

```
#include <algorithm>
size = std::remove_if(pData, pData + size, [](char c) { return c == '\n'; }) - pData;
pData[size] = 0; // optional
```

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Simple, modern, effective, efficient.

Comment: Beats out others seeing as how it's essentially a one-liner as well.

Comment: Great solution, however size is of the type long not char *

Comment: what if the line breaks are using `\r\n` instead of bare `\n`?

Comment: @Remy: The file is opened in text-mode with line ending conversions enabled.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest approach is to make a second buffer the size of the original array.

```
int len = size;

char* newBufer = calloc(len,sizeof(char));
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int nlCount = 0;

for(i=0; i<len; i++) {
  if(pData[i] != '\n') {
    newBuffer[j++] = pData[i];
  } else {
    nlCount++;
  }
}

printf("Finished copying array without newlines. Total newlines removed: %d",nlCount);
```

The added benefit here is since you calloc'ed instead of malloc'ing your array, all values are zero initially, so in this case, once you are done copying, the data at (len-nlCount) through to (len) will all be zero (ie: '\0') so it is automatically null-terminated, like a string would be anyways. Don't forget to free() the array when you are done.

Answer (score 1):

In place removal:

```
void strip_newlines(char* p) {
    char* q = p;
    while (p != 0 && *p != '\0') {
        if (*p == '\n') {
            p++;
            *q = *p;
        } 
        else {
            *q++ = *p++;
        }
    }
    *q = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Useless `size` argument... and what if there's an embedded NUL?  Also copies the character following `'\n'` multiple times uselessly, and doesn't terminate the string or provide any way to find the new size.

Comment: oops I put the size there when I was going to do a for loop...then I switched to the pointers only...will remove.

Comment: Don't forget to add the new line character to the end of the character array when the while loop completes.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
void Read::readFile()
{ 
    FILE * fp = fopen(this->filename,"rt"); 
    if (fp)
    {
        char *pData = NULL;

        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END); 
        long size = ftell(fp); 
        if (size != -1L)
        {
            pData = new char[size];
            if (size > 0)
            {
                fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET); 
                size = fread(pData, sizeof(char), size, fp);
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);

        if (size < 0)
        {
            delete[] pData;
            pData = NULL;
        }
        else if (size > 0)
        {
            char *start = pData;
            char *end = start + size;

            char *ptr = (char*) memchr(pData, '\n', size);
            while (ptr)
            {
                int len = 1;
                if ((ptr > start) && ((*ptr-1) == '\r'))
                {
                    --ptr;
                    ++len;
                }

                memmove(ptr, ptr+len, end - (ptr+len));
                end -= len;

                ptr = (char*) memchr(ptr, '\n', end - ptr);
            }

            size = (end - start);
        }

        this->data = pData; 
        this->size = size; 
    }
}
```